# Rails Validation for users email - only want it to validate when a user signs up or updates email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, models

I have a User model with the usual attributes such as email and hashed_password etc. I want to write a validation that checks for the presence of an email address but only when

1) there isn't one stored in the database for this object (i.e. this is a new user signing up)

2) the user is trying to update their email address.

My current validations

```
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :email_confirmation

  validates_confirmation_of :email
```

are obviously preventing me from updating any attributes. I thought of using

validates_presence_of :email , :if :email_validation_required?

```
def email_validation_required?
self.email.blank?
end
```

But that wont help with scenario 2 as it will return true because the user does have an <strike>password</strike> email address in the db.

I cant work out how i can limit it to just those 2 scenarios above.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think EmFi is on to something. But I don't think the `validates_presence_of :email` should be holding you up. The `email` should always be present - if it is left blank in the form the parameter will not mess with your save of the user. If it is entered in the form, even for update, it should have an `email_confirmation` along for the ride.

Give this a try:

```
validates_presence_of :email
validates_presence_of :email_confirmation, :if => :email_changed?

validates_confirmation_of :email
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply barry, your right about it not holding me up. I was just replicating the code for password_confirmation for email_confirmation but that has different requirements. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10):

you have two options. one is to use `:on`. by default, they are set to `:on => :save`, but you can do something like this this

```
validates_presence_of :email, :on => :create
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :email, :on => :update
```

the other options is to use `:if`, and then pass in a method name or a proc. so something like

```
validates_presence_of :email, :if => :should_validate
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :email, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.signup_stage > 2 }
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: hi matt thanks for you help. I had thought of using a method with :if but got stumped on how to writ the logic inside it. I was wondering if there was a way without having to introduce more attributes to my model. I notice in your last example you mention a signup_stage attribute.

Comment: I was just giving rather generic examples. On re-reading your question, why will the email be blank in your model if the user has a password in the db?

Comment: sorry that password was a typo - it should have read email. Edited the post.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use an :if clause on the validation that uses the ActiveRecord::Dirty methods:

```
validates_presence_of :email, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.email_changed?}
```

N.B. Only works in Rails 2.1 or later.